# Is there a corresponding immutable enumMap in guava?

Tags: java, immutability, guava, enum-map

I recently learnt about the benefits of EnumMap in Java and would like to replace the existing `ImmutableMap<OccupancyType, BigDecimal>` to EnumMap. However, I'd also like the immutable property offered by ImmutableMap.

- Is there a variant, ImmutableEnumMap available in guava ?
- In terms of storage which one (EnumMap vs ImmutableMap) performs better ?
- I couldn't find a comparison of the two. I'd appreciate if someone can point me to a link or  give some insights on the efficiency of the two data structures ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Guava contributor here.

Guava doesn't currently have an `ImmutableEnumMap` variant, but if it did, it would probably just be a wrapper around an `EnumMap`.  (That said, slightly better immutable implementations are possible.)

`EnumMap` will perform better than the basic `ImmutableMap`, in any event; it's difficult or impossible to beat.

(I'll [file an issue](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1047) to investigate adding an `ImmutableMap` variant for enum key types, though.)

---

Update: Guava 14 adds [`Maps.immutableEnumMap()`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/fec0dbc4634006a6162cfd4d0d09c962073ddf40/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Maps.java#L146).

Comment: Thanks. Would you happen to have a comparison of the two handy ?

Comment: I mean, there's not exactly a well-defined metric by which to compare them, but I can tell you that `ImmutableMap` is only slightly better than `HashMap`, so `EnumMap` should beat both by around the same factor.

Comment: Update: `ImmutableEnumMap` [has been added.](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/detail?r=835a7397fabb05a764a8008f4151c97f821a29ef)

Comment: Yup, `ImmutableEnumMap` is now in Guava 14.0. =)

Comment: Note: `immutableEnumMap()` does not return an `EnumMap`. So if you want this because you want to pass an immutable object to something expecting an `EnumMap` (in the same way that you might pass an `ImmutableMap` to something expecting a `Map`), it won't work.

Answer (score 14):

I was just wanted to provide an example now that `ImmutableEnumMap` is in [Guava 14.0](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/detail?r=835a7397fabb05a764a8008f4151c97f821a29ef), because it's a package-private class, so you can't do `ImmutableEnumMap.of()`.  You have to do `Maps.immutableEnumMap()` instead.

```
private final ImmutableMap<MyEnum, String> myEnumMap = Maps.immutableEnumMap(ImmutableMap.of(
        MyEnum.A,   "A",
        MyEnum.B,   "B",
        MyEnum.C,   "C"
        ));
```

Not sure if there's a more natural syntax.

Comment: Within that call to `Maps.immutableEnumMap` you can use a `ImmutableMap.<MyEnum, String>builder().put(MyEnum.A, "A").build()` to add more than 5 values to the map.

Answer (score 3):

As the guava ImmutableEnumMap is still marked beta as of version 14, I would suggest using a unmodifiable view of a enum map and then throwing away the original reference to the enum map to ensure that it is immutable.

Example (in a constructor):

```
Map entries = new EnumMap <SomeEnum, T>(SomeEnum.class);
... // (fill in entries)
this.entries = Collections.unmodifiableMap(entries);
```