# How to initialize empty ImmutableEnumMap using guava?

Tags: java, guava, enum-map

I have a constructor which takes `Map<ProcessInfoEnum, String>` as a parameter. So I am initializing `NO_OPERATION` variable like as shown below with empty immutable map.

```
  public static final Processor NO_OPERATION = new Processor(ImmutableMap.<ProcessInfoEnum, String>of());
  private final Map<ProcessInfoEnum, String> values;

  public Processor(Map<ProcessInfoEnum, String> values) {
    this.values = values;
  }
```

Now I have changed my constructor to use `EnumMap` as shown below due to some design change:

```
  public Processor(EnumMap<ProcessInfoEnum, String> values) {
    this.values = values;
  }
```

Now how can I write same equivalent line for `NO_OPERATION` but with `ImmutableEnumMap` so that it can initialize empty immutable enum map?

```
  // obviously this doesn't work
  public static final Processor NO_OPERATION = new Processor(ImmutableEnumMap.<ProcessInfoEnum, String>of());
  private final EnumMap<ProcessInfoEnum, String> values;

  public Processor(EnumMap<ProcessInfoEnum, String> values) {
    this.values = values;
  }
```

Since `ImmutableEnumMap` is a package-private class so I cannot do `ImmutableEnumMap.of()`. Is there any other way?

Comment: please consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244402/is-there-a-corresponding-immutable-enummap-in-guava

Comment: likely Maps.immutableEnumMap(ImmutableMap.of());

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work and it asked me to change the constructor definitions to `ImmutableMap`

Comment: it says that Guava 14 adds Maps.immutableEnumMap().

Comment: Yes but that line doesn't work still. I have tried that.

Comment: show us how it does not work, please

Comment: @OlegBogdanov I already mentioned when I add that line, `it asked me to change the constructor of Processor class definitions to ImmutableMap instead of EnumMap`

Comment: oh I see, sorry. Well, guava does not care it its EnumMap or ordinary Map that becomes immutable, both types are typed through `ImmutableMap`, is that a problem for you to make that change? You could go even wider to `AbstractMap`

Comment: Why does your `Processor` constructor need to have an `EnumMap` as a parameter, instead of just a `Map`?  If there were some operations that `EnumMap` provided that `Map` didn't provide, then I could see why it would be necessary.  But other than `clone()`, I don't see any new operations.  So it doesn't seem necessary for the parameter to be `EnumMap`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no public ImmutableEnumMap type, so you'd have to type it as ImmutableMap anyway - so you can just use ImmutableMap.of() without worrying about the enum part.  There is no difference.

Comment: In  my case, my constructor takes EnumMap as the input parameter and if I declare `NO_OPERATION` as `public static final Processor NO_OPERATION = new Processor(ImmutableMap.of());`, I get a compilation error asking me to change constructor to `ImmutableMap` instead of using `EnumMap`.

Comment: If your constructor takes EnumMap then you must create an EnumMap. ImmutableEnumMap extends ImmutableMap; it does not extend EnumMap. You will have to create a mutable EnumMap, there is no other choice. All EnumMaps are by definition mutable.  (You may wish to reconsider the decision to accept an EnumMap in your constructor in the first place.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman "All EnumMaps are by definition mutable"--isn't it possible in theory to extend `EnumMap` to create your own `ImmutableEnumMap` class by overriding `put`, `putAll`, and `remove` to throw exceptions?  Or is there some subtle reason this wouldn't work?  (I'm not suggesting this as the solution.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Oh, all right then.  I guess I have to go to confession now for suggesting the possibility.